# Use Python Pool with context manager or close and join

Tags: python, pool

The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) has examples in the format of

```
with Pool() as p:
    p.map(do)
```

but I see a lot of people using the format below.

```
p = Pool()
p.map(do)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Which is more desirable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think using `Pool` as a context manager (e.g., `with ...`) is desirable. It's a newer addition to `Pool`, and it lets you more cleanly encapsulate the lifespan of the pool.

One thing to be aware of is, that when the context manager exits, it will terminate the pool and any ongoing tasks. This means that you still want to do `p.join()` in some cases. Your example doesn't require this, because `p.map` will block execution until the task is done anyway:

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map

Therefore, in the second example, the call to `.join()` is unnecessary, as `.map()` will block until all tasks have completed.

However, using `.map_async` would make `.join` useful:

```
with Pool() as p:
    p.map_async(do_something, range(100))
    # Do something else while tasks are running
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

**Edit**: as Facundo Olano points out, `.close()` must always be called before `.join()`, as stated in the docs:

> Wait for the worker processes to exit. One must call close() or terminate() before using join().
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join

Comment: I think `p.close()` is also necessary in the async example, the doc says "One must call close() or terminate() before using join()", and I can confirm there's an error if I attempt joining before closing in python 3.6

Comment: @FacundoOlano, thanks for catching this! I've fixed my async example above.

Comment: Dear all, one thing that kept me wondering was whether one should call "close" and "join" within the Pool context manager, or outside. Would someone elucidate it further? Sincerely

Comment: @PhilipeRiskallaLeal it has to be within the context. p will no longer exist after the code exits "with" context

Comment: @ThangDo This isn't actually the case. Try it out in the interpreter: `p` is still in scope after the context manager block.

Comment: @ThangDo Though you are correct that `.join()` should be called inside the context, because when the context exits, it stops all tasks even if they're not completed.

Comment: Am I correct that the second option fails to correctly clean up the pool if `p.map` fails with an uncought exception? The long-form version of the context manager is actually the try-excepy-finally syntax, to ensure you don't leave a broken pool with a mess of worker threads hogging memory if the thing crashes.

Comment: @MRule, yes I believe you are correct.